# Second monitor doesn't show image after waking up - Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, suspend, 20.10

For the last few months I've been dealing with issues when connecting a monitor/TV to my laptop. When it first boots it works fine, the issue comes when I suspend the laptop and I try to use the second monitor. The OS detects it, but it shows nothing but a black screen, so I have to reboot so that the monitor can show any image. If I open a window it will open on the second screen and can drag it to the laptop built-in screen.

I guess it has to do with the suspension thing but I can't figure out what it is. Has anyone faced this issue before? Any further information will be provided if requested.

Thanks in advance.